# Does a Compact Subset Remain Compact in the Alexandroff Compactification?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

Let $X$ be a topological space that enjoys the Hausdorff property, $K \subset X$ be compact, and $\widetilde{X}$ be the Alexandroff compactification of $X$. Is it true that $K \subset \widetilde{X}$ is compact as well?

My attempt to show this:

Let $W_\lambda \subset \widetilde{X}$ be an open cover of $K$, i.e. we have
\begin{align}
K \subset \bigcup_\lambda W_\lambda.
\end{align}
Assume that we have $\lambda_0$ s.t. $\infty \in W_{\lambda_0}$, then
\begin{align}
K \backslash W_{\lambda_0} \subset \bigcup_{\lambda \neq \lambda_0} W_\lambda \subset X.
\end{align}
Since $W_{\lambda_0}$ is open and contains $\infty$, it is true that there is $C \subset X$ compact, such that $K \backslash W_{\lambda_0} = K \cap C \subset X$ is compact ($X$ is Hausdorff).
Hence, there is a finite subcover
\begin{align}
K \subset \bigcup_{i = 0, \dots, N} W_{\lambda_i},
\end{align}
for some natural number $N$ and hence, $K \subset \widetilde{X}$ is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is okay. *But there is nothing to prove.*

The Alexandroff compactification $\tilde X$ of any space $X$ has the property that $X$ is an open **subspace** of $\tilde X$. Thus each $Y \subset X$ receives its original topology when regarded as a subspace of $\tilde X$. But compactness is an *intrinsic property* of topological spaces and therefore the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Well, I think I see it: The two topologies that we would consider would be 
$\mathscr{O}_Y = \{ U \cap Y | U \in O_X \}$ and 
$\widetilde{\mathscr{O}}_Y = \{ U \cap Y |  U \in O_{\widetilde{X}} \}$.
The only non trivial intersections in the tilde topology involve the $U$s that do not feature $\infty$ and hence, the two sets are identical for $Y \subset X$.